# Redmine not receiving emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Please help.

I wanted to set up in Redmine 4.1.1 an email read.
This is my code that I am executing in CLI:

```sh
bundle exec rake -f Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=outlook.office365.com port=993 username=user@domain.com password=PASSWORD ssl=1 project=mars-test-do-not-delete folder=main move_on_success=completed move_on_failure=failed no_permission_check=1 unknown_user=accept no_account_notice=1 --trace
```

But I am getting this output when I execute the code:

```
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Redmine::IMAP
/home/seven/redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:121:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/seven/redmine/app/models/mailer.rb:630:in `with_synched_deliveries'
/home/seven/redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:120:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/seven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_imap
```

This is only half of the output.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Anything :)

The SMTP works without any problems. I am using an Exchange MS server for email.

Thank you.

---

**As an update:**
I set up a new server ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Installed redmine 4.0.6
Ruby 2.5.0
rake 13.0.1

Now when I run:

```
rake -f Rakefile --silent redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=outlook.office365.com port=993 username=EMAIL_USER password=PASSWORD ssl=true project=mars-test-do-not-delete folder=main move_on_success=processed move_on_failure=failed no_permission_check=1 unknown_user=accept 1 > /dev/null
```

I get this:

```
Your Gemfile lists the gem redmine_crm (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Redmine::IMAP
/home/seven/redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:121:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/seven/redmine/app/models/mailer.rb:612:in `with_synched_deliveries'
/home/seven/redmine/lib/tasks/email.rake:120:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/seven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/seven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/seven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_imap
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I didi check the redmine_crm, to mu surprise in the Gemfile I have only one reference to it, so I do not fully understand why I get this error to;/

Comment: It seems the plugin is also mentioned somewhere else in another Gemfile. Did you install the plugin first using the "bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=plugin's name RAILS_ENV=environment" or remove this from plugin Gemfile and run it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In file:

```
/ROOT_PATH_TO_REDMINE/lib/tasks/email.rake
```

I needed to add one line on the top of the file:

```
require 'redmine/imap.rb'
```

That solved the problem.